# How can I change the order of integration in this case?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I was solving this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhd08.jpg) and I have no idea how should I "Exchange the order of integration to obtain the desired result." I don't think I can use Fubini's theorem since there is a variable y in the integral inside. That is,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^y f(y)dtdy}\ \ne \int_{0}^{y}{\int_{0}^\infty f(y)dydt}$$

$$$$
I looked into slader and found this answer
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl({\int_{0}^{y}{dt}}\biggl)f(y)dy\ = \int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl({\int_{0}^{y}{f(y)dy}\biggl)dt}\ = \int_{0}^{\infty}{P(Y>y)dy}$$
which I believe is wrong (because the integral is happening on $\{(t,\ y)|\ 0\le t \le y,\ 0\le y \le \infty \}$). So how can I change the order? Or is ther any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{y} dt dy=\int_0^{\infty} \int_t^{\infty} f(y)dy dt=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y>t)dt$. Now you can  change the dummy variable on right to $y$ if you like.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The original integral is on $0\le t\le y\le\infty$, so you could write $\int_0^\infty dt\int_t^\infty f(y)dy$. But Slader is right as well, as @KaviRamaMurthy explained.